# Cannot access Apache Zeppelin server from browser

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have downloaded Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0. The problem that I am facing is that when I try to start the Zeppelin server using *bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start* it says ok  but I cannot access it from the browser(using the default localhost:8080). If I run *bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh status* it says that the server is already running.
Also, I tried to start the server using *bin/zeppelin.sh* and this time some information is displayed in the terminal but with no effect.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your last logs? in `logs/` It should be `INFO [2017-03-02 15:45:34,183] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:196) - Done, zeppelin server started`.

Comment: Yes, that is the last line but still does not start when going to localhost:8080. Also there are a couple of exceptions regarding the npm installation.. I don't know why it is needed due to the fact that on windows I follow the same steps and it works. Right now I am following this tutorial: [link](https://support.instaclustr.com/hc/en-us/articles/214940967-Using-Apache-Zeppelin-with-Instaclustr-Spark-Cassandra-Tutorial) and I will return with another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tutorial from their website ([link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/install/install.html#building-from-source)) I managed to run it. This implies building it from sources. Also, I had to wait a couple of minutes before the zeppelin was available at localhost:8080 (even though in the terminal "server started [OK]" was displayed

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was getting errors in my browser console like the screenshot below.

After cleaning the cache, it works.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe this was actually the answer!

Answer (score -3):

[Icant able to connect to the server using zeppelin notebook Can any tell me the solution

[image]